# Combine data from 2 forms to one sheet depending on the date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms, google-sheets-query

I have 2 forms and I have their results on the same sheet. I used the following formula

```
=Query({importrange(...);importrange(...)}, "SELECT * where Col1 is not null")
```

I want to have **all** the results from 1 form and the results **depending on the date** from the other form on the same sheet.

I have tried the following formula for July

```
=Query({importrange(...);importrange(...)}, "WHERE month(Col1)=5")
```

but it shows ONLY the results with July in the date from both forms.

How can I combine the results?

Comment: Can you share an example of your data, what you get currently and what you want as an outcome?

Comment: Please include a sample of your desired result, and it could also be useful a sample of the response sheet where you import the data from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2**
*(following OP's [concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62381523/combine-data-from-2-forms-to-one-sheet-depending-on-the-date-in-google-sheets#comment110443806_62384987))*

> ...Looks like it works only when there are entries with July in the date in the second spreadsheet. I need all the entries in the first spreadsheet to be visualized at any time

We can easily fix that by wrapping the whole formula with the [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) function

```
=IFERROR({QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxx","form1!A1:E"), "where Col1 is not null");
   QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxx","form2!A1:E"), "where Col1 is not null and month(todate(Col1))=6",0)},
          QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxx","form1!A1:E"), "where Col1 is not null"))
```

Just make sure that `Col1` (the *Timestamp*) in your results sheet is formatted as `Date time`

***This final formula says:***
**Import** data from the **1st sheet** and under it **append** data from the **2nd sheet based on a certain month**.
**If** that month is missing (which results to an error), import data from **just** the 1st sheet.

---

**EDIT**
*(following OP's [clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62381523/google-sheets-data-from-2-forms-to-one-sheet-depending-on-the-date/62384987#comment110362598_62384987))*

> ...but my results are not on the same spreadsheets. I'd like to keep them on different spreadsheets.

Since there are **different spreadsheets involved** you must use the `IMPORTRANGE` function (as you very correctly already do).
Then the formula would be:

```
={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxx","form1!A1:E"), "where Col1 is not null");
   QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxx","form2!A1:E"), "where Col1 is not null and month(todate(Col1))=6",0)}
```

*(As before please adjust ranges to your needs. Just make sure you keep the same number of columns)*

*NOTES:

1. Though July is the 7th month, we use `month(todate(Col1))=6`. That is because **in "query language" January is month 0 and not 1**.

2. In our second part we use as headers `0`. This way we get to avoid returning them for the second query.

3. Since the imports come from forms we keep open ranges so when new answers are submitted, then get imported as well.*

---

If all your sheets are in the **same spreadsheet**, you do not need `IMPORTRANGE`.
Using `INDEX` -which is much "lighter"- your formula would be:

```
={QUERY({form1!A2:O29}, "where Col1 is not null");
   QUERY({form2!A2:O29}, "WHERE month(Col1)=6")}
```

Now your **`form2` results will be placed under the ones from `form1`**

---

Having an additional query, you can **have them both ordered by the `timestamp` in column 1**

```
=QUERY({QUERY({form1!A2:O29}, "where Col1 is not null");
   QUERY({form2!A2:O29}, "WHERE month(Col1)=7")},"order by Col1")
```

*(Please adjust all sheet names and ranges to your needs)*

Comment: Thank you for your help Marikamitsos but my results are not on the same spreadsheets. I'd like to keep them on different spreadsheets

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Please check the edited answer. Also, please accept/improve or reject my edits to your question. I cannot edit any questions any more till you do.

Comment: Thank you again Marikamitsos! I understand the formula but I'm getting an error

**In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows**

Comment: Your ranges do NOT match. You need to fix that.

Comment: I used the following
`={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxx","Log!A:H"), "where Col1 is not null");
   QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("yyyyyy","Log!A:H"), "where Col1 is not null and month(todate(Col1))=6",0)}
`
The ranges are the same...

Comment: Then that means that there are no entries for `month(todate(Col1))=6` which is the month of **July**.

Comment: Looks like it works only when there are entries with July in the date in the second spreadsheet. I need all the entries in the first spreadsheet to be visualized at any time